# Bootstrap Filtering Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to make a filtering gallery for 3 days now, no success at all. Every code I found, or write by myself it doesn't work. I'm using the starter bootstrap 4 template which includes the latest JQuery version, so I have no clue at all, why this is not working, as it should be. The js file is also connected to the HTML.

HTML

```
<section id="projects" class="padding">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center col-12">
                <div class="projects-filter">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline current" data-filter="*">Összes</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline" data-filter="kiemelt">Kiemelt</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline" data-filter="molinok">Molinók</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline" data-filter="berendezesek">Berendezések</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline" data-filter="iparmuveszet">Iparművészet</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="projects-content d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="single-project col-4 molinok">
                    <div class="single-project-image">
                        <img src="img/projects/alutechnika01.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="single-project-desc">
                        <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="single-project col-4 kiemelt">
                    <div class="single-project-image">
                        <img src="img/projects/alutechnika01.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="single-project-desc">
                        <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="single-project col-4 molinok">
                    <div class="single-project-image">
                        <img src="img/projects/alutechnika01.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="single-project-desc">
                        <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).load(function(){
var $container = $('.projects-content');
$container.isotope({
    filter: '*',
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    }
});

$('.projects-filter button').click(function(){
    $('.projects-filter .current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector,
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
     });
     return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: 1. please create a [mre] 2. "doesn't work" is a completely useless problem description

Answer (score 0):

In `filter:selector`, prepend `selector` with `.` to make it `className`. Source - https://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html.

```js
var $container = $('.projects-content');
$container.isotope({
  filter: '*',
  animationOptions: {
    duration: 750,
    easing: 'linear',
    queue: false
  }
});

$('.projects-filter button').click(function() {
  $('.projects-filter .current').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');

  var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');

  $container.isotope({
    filter: (selector == '*') ? '*' : '.' + selector,
    animationOptions: {
      duration: 750,
      easing: 'linear',
      queue: false
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<section id="projects" class="padding">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center col-12">
      <div class="projects-filter">
        <button class="btn btn-outline current" data-filter="*">Összes</button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline" data-filter="kiemelt">Kiemelt</button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline" data-filter="molinok">Molinók</button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline" data-filter="berendezesek">Berendezések</button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline" data-filter="iparmuveszet">Iparművészet</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="projects-content d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="single-project col-4 molinok">
        <div class="single-project-image">
          <img src="img/projects/alutechnika01.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="single-project-desc">
          <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="single-project col-4 kiemelt">
        <div class="single-project-image">
          <img src="img/projects/alutechnika01.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="single-project-desc">
          <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="single-project col-4 molinok">
        <div class="single-project-image">
          <img src="img/projects/alutechnika01.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="single-project-desc">
          <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```